# How to design css layout of "metro line" without station or line name cover

Tags: html, css, less

I have an array of metro lines and stations. What I want to do is display the `line names on the up center of line`, and the `station names right below the station`, and lines and stations are connected.
What's important is that `line names shouldn't exceed line, and shouldn't cover other line names`, and `station names should also not cover other station names`, no matter how long station names or line names are.
The problem now is **when station name is too long, it will cover other station names**.

```
.main{
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}
.line{
  height: 2px;
  min-width: 32px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
 .line-name{
   margin: -20px 16px 0;
 }
.station{
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.station-name {
  margin: 0 16px -20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div class="main">
 <div class="station">
  <span class="station-name">first station</span>
 </div>
 <div class="line">
  <span class="line-name">short line</span>
 </div>
 <div class="station">
  <span class="station-name">loooooong station name</span>
 </div>
 <div class="line">
  <span class="line-name">very very very very loooooooong line name</span>
 </div>
 <div class="station">
  <span class="station-name">this on name</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Target effect is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyknT.png)
current code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ueq21afw/, and station name cover each other.
Could anybody help me out of this? thanks.

Comment: Please share any screenshot for required styling and structure. Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui pic added

Comment: Finally I used canvas to solve this problem, which can get text width before it's inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I worked it out using canvas.

1. I created a canvas first.
2. Then I insert all the texts(ex: `今日の天気 Station`) into the canvas, and kept them in an array.
3. Meanwhile I got the lengths of all the newly inserted texts.
   By doing all these above, I can calculate which position I should put the texts, circles and lines. And I drew all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I tried structuring the html code all in other way. https://jsbin.com/gapecapopo/edit?html,css,output

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  /* flex: 1; */
  background-color: #EEE;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.line {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.line::before {
  content: 'o';
  position:relative;
  bottom: -8px;
}

.station-name {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
     <div class="column">
       <div class="station-name">This station aaaa have very long name</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line-name">line a</div>
     </div>
      <div class="column">
       <div class="station-name">station b short</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line-name">line b</div>
     </div>
      <div class="column">
       <div class="station-name">this station cccc have very long nameee</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line-name">line c</div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: thanks, but when station name is very long, line should grow too

Comment: @user2306775 it seems growing fine too.

Comment: I tried a quite long station name, it didn't work quite well. And I've added my code which also has problem when station name grows very long: https://jsfiddle.net/ueq21afw/

Comment: It seems that I didn't make it quite clear enough, line name should be placed on the up middle of line, while station name should be place right down station, and when line name grows, it should not exceed line width, and when station name grow, it should not cover other station names. In your example, when the names below points grow too long,  seems it does not work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I just update your code with few **CSS** and **structure** changes. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  position:relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li:after {
  background-color: #000;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

li.station {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

li.station:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 3px);  
  left: calc(50% - 3px);
  z-index: 1;
}

li.station:last-child:after {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Line Text 1</li>
  <li class="station">Station Name 1</li>
  <li>Line Text 2</li>
  <li class="station">Station Name 2</li>
  <li>Line Text 3</li>
  <li class="station">Station Name 3Station Name 3Station Name 3Station Name 3Station Name 3Station Name 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in your code, when station name grows quite long, it will be turned to multi lines, which breaks the whole structure, is there any suggested solution?

Comment: @yuant I just update the above code snippet. Now if station/line text grows quite long it'll stay on a single line. Thanks

Comment: staion name and line name should cross each other horizontally. Finally I used canvas which can get text width beforehand. Any way, thanks a lot